# How do I run javascript test code in Netbeans or other IDE?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, google-chrome-devtools

I am a bit of a Javascript noob, and I have been mostly doing my coding through Codecademy or CodeSchool where you just type in your code, hit Run, and the website lets you know if you're wrong or right.
 I'm now working with Free Code Camp, and they have these challenges where I can plug in the code, but it does not give me error messages or lets me know if I'm missing semicolons or if I just want to test a section of code at a time as I build it, etc.
 I am used to using an IDE for things like this for Java or Toad for SQL, but I found that NetBeans doesn't have anything where I can just dump code, compile it, run it, and see the end results.
 I tried Chrome Dev Tools, but it seems like there is a Javascript console, but nothing where I can write code and run it from there...unless I am totally mistaken, which is what I would like to know. :)
 If someone could let me know how to do this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Perdue

Comment: http://liveweave.com is great! It supports Visual Studio-like code hinting...which makes learning a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [post](http://www.sitepoint.com/7-code-playgrounds/).

You can use any of the following:

1. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)
2. [CodePen](http://codepen.io)
3. [CSS Deck](http://cssdeck.com)
4. [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com)
5. [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com)
6. [Liveweave](http://liveweave.com)

Comment: Thanks so much for this list! This is exactly what I was looking for. I will try this out tonight when I get home. :D

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome Dev Tools you can paste or write code code in the console and run it, basically it's just like Code School prompt. It can also identify your errors and show them.

Just press `F12` to open the console.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I opened the console, press F12, and it just returned me to Chrome. It didn't allow me to enter in any code at all. :S

Comment: `F12` is the shortcut used to get to the console.. if you are already in the console then the cursor will be blinking type any js code over there it will work fine